# Sensor Array Position Calibration in Anisotropic Media

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-physics, mathematics, signal-processing, algorithms

#### Problem.

I have a sensor array consisting of $n \gg 4$ receivers at unknown locations $\langle x_n, y_n, z_n\rangle$ embedded in an anisotropic medium whose index of refraction varies as a known function of depth:

$$n(z) = a - be^{cz}$$

...where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are known constants.

I additionally have $m \geq 1$ "calibration transmitters" with known locations $\langle x_m, y_m, z_m \rangle$. In the case $m > 1$, all $m$ transmitters have the same $x$ and $y$ coordinate (i.e. they form a vertical line).

Each transmitter emits a single signal, not necessarily simultaneously, at *unknown* emission times. Each signal is observed by all $n$ receivers, and the time of arrival at each receiver is recorded.

Using *only* the times of arrival at each receiver, and the known locations of the transmitter(s), I wish to recover the "true" location of each receiver.

---

#### What I have so far.

Notice that many (all?) standard TDoA localization techniques cannot be applied, as these are designed to locate a *single* source given arrival times at several receivers with *well known* locations

Since the anisotropic medium in question has a refractive index which varies as an exponential function of depth, the rays can be "reversed" (i.e. the transmitters may be treated as receivers, and vice versa). Still, there is insufficient information in the case $m < 4$, and in the case $m > 1$ all receivers lie in a line, posing a problem for most (all?) TDoA based localization algorithms.

Since the true emission time(s) are unknown, all I have to work with are the time differences.

What I'm doing right now is to perform a linear approximation with [metric multidimensional scaling](https://cecas.clemson.edu/%7Estb/publications/miccalib_mds_extensions_eusipco2004.pdf) (known to some as *principal coordinate analysis*. This works only in the case $m > 1$, and still does not fully recover the receiver positions uniquely, as the transmitters lie in a line.

Comment: Are the signals from the different transmitters distinguishable? Also this problem is probably better suited for signal processing stackexchange.

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to some small number of pulses?

Comment: @Jagerber48 Got it! And yes, the signals are distinguishable. The data I'm working with has arrival times pre-labeled by transmitter ID.

Comment: @UVphoton Yes, each $m \geq 1$ receiver emits a single pulse, which is received at each sensor. So, we have in total $m$ pulses.

Comment: @10GeV Suppose you know one emitter is at $(x, y, z)$ and emits a pulse a time $t$. Suppose you know a detector is at $(x', y', z')$. Do you have a theory which will allow you to calculate the time $t'$ that the detector will receive the signal? That theory doesn't seem straightforward to me, It seems like light will take a curved path through continuously varying index of refraction. (or in other words a spherical wavefront emitted by the emitter will become distorted as it travels through the medium).

Comment: @Jagerber48 In this case, it's relatively easy to compute the transit time both analytically and numerically. I have some code that does so, given the coordinates of an emitter and detector. Anecdotally, for this particular case, it turns out that the transit time is identical if you were to swap their locations.

Answer (score 0):

I’d trying simple least squares regression.

Generate a model function as follows. The model will take in $3n+m$ Unknown parameters: $(x_n, y_n, z_n)$ for each receiver position and $t'_m$ for each emitter emission time. The model will also include the $3m$ known transmitter positions $(x_m, y_m, z_m)$ for each transmitter. The model will output $n\times m$ times $t_{nm}$ for the detection of each signal on each receiver.

The least squares problem will compare the predicted arrival times $t_{nm}$ to measured arrival times $\hat{t}_{nm}$ and use the sum of the squared differences $\phi = \sum_{nm}(\hat{t}_{nm}-t_{nm})^2$ as the cost measure to optimize on. i.e. the algorithm will modify the $3n+m$ input parameters in an intelligent way to try to minimize $\phi$. It's possible that this approach will not work due to sensitivity to initial conditions or the presence of local minima, but if it was me I would give it a shot.

I'm not sure if the minimization problem described above is "convex", but if it is you could try a convex optimization algorithm as well if least squares doesn't work.